# WCF REST WebInvoke UriTemplate & https Issue

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, webinvoke

My WCF service works with WebInvoke attributes and using httpGetEnabled.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate = "/Function1")]
void Function1(Stream input);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate = "/Function2")]
void Function2( Stream input );
```

When I try to get it to work with https, I cannot access the UriTemplates. I can however, access the svc and wsdl.

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="SslBehavior" name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SslBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

This service is hosted in IIS 7. Is there something obvious that I'm missing? I've tried as many combinations of configuration as possible. When I try to post to one of the WebInvoke links I get a 404 error.

Another company will be posting to this service, which is why it must be RESTfull

**Edit**

I did try this in the bindings node:

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SslBinding" transferMode="Streamed">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

And set the BindingConfiguration on the endpoint. Same issue :(

Comment: Did you set the binding's security in your config?

Comment: see my answer below.  You may want to try setting security mode to Transport.

Comment: i think you should listen to Tim. Try security mode="Transport" instead of "None". Also, you may set one of the end points address starting with "https://"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting seucrity mode to Transport:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SslBinding" transferMode="Streamed">
      <security mode="Transport">  
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />     
    </security>     
  </binding>   
</webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Ahh! guess I need to read more into this. I was setting the mode to None.  Thanks! that seems to have done the trick

Comment: I can access it locally now, however, when I publish it I cannot access it from external resources :/

Comment: Any differences between your local box and the environment you published it to?